# Pikaday.js: How to disbale days in calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pikaday

I have a calendar and I want to set a few days to disable. Does anyone have experience with this? On github it says:

```
disableDayFn: callback function that gets passed a Date object for each day in view. Should return true to disable selection of that day.
```

But how can I use this?

```
var bookingPicker = new Pikaday(
            {
                field: $(self.options.calendarInput, container)[0],
                container: $(self.options.calendarContainer, container)[0],
                minDate: new Date(),
                bound: false,
                firstDay: 1,
            onOpen: function () {
                this.disableDayFn(23); //<--- ???
            },
            onSelect: function (date) {

            },
            onDraw: function (date) {
                console.log("NEW MONTH")
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var bookingPicker = new Pikaday(
        {
            field: $(self.options.calendarInput, container)[0],
            container: $(self.options.calendarContainer, container)[0],
            minDate: new Date(),
            bound: false,
            firstDay: 1,
        onOpen: function () {
            this.disableDayFn(23); //<--- ???
        },
        onSelect: function (date) {

        },
        onDraw: function (date) {
            console.log("NEW MONTH")
        },
        disableDayFn: function(dateTime){
          /* here you can access each day shown and disable those in your range. To disable just return true*/
       } 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> So every date you can see on the picker is passed, just do whatever checks you want in the function against that date.  Here's an example using a string array of dates that uses moment.js to qualify equality.

```
var validDateArray = ["2017-JAN-01", "2017-JAN-02", "2017-JAN-03"]
```

> in the picker:

```
disableDayFn: (dateToCheck: Date) => {

  if (validDateArray == undefined) {
    console.log("...validDateArray == undefined");
    return true;
  }

  let d1 = Moment(dateToCheck).format("YYYY-MMM-DD");

  for (let d2 of validDateArray) {
    if (d1 == d2) {
      console.log("...date is valid");
      return false; 
    }
  }

  console.log("...date is not valid");
  return true;
}
```